# Creating surface Controller in Umbraco 5.0.1 using "Visual Web Developer 2010 Express"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco, vwdexpress

I have been currently facing problems with creating surface controller in Umbraco 5.0.1 and Visual web developer.I have followed Shannons blog in creating surface controllers but for that I had to create a

1.new MVC project and

2.refer all the umbraco dlls again in that MVC project.

Is that necessary? Can I not create a surface controller in the existing umbraco project which I installed using web platform installer.

One more question theres no Properties folder for Umbraco 5.0.1 in vwd 2010 express.Do I need to create it separately

Its getting pretty hard to find some documentation for Umbraco 5.0.1 and much harder for Visual Web developer

I am just a newbie who was introduced to Umbraco recently

Guidance much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Umbraco 5 directly,now we have made a Single MVC project(using ASP.NET MVC3 template) and installed the Umbraco 5 CMS for MVC3 using Nuget package manager.So now we have the controllers and all other folders that come with MVC and also the folders that come with Umbraco.So now we are directly using a normal cotroller to post a form data instead of surface controller.
Hope this is the right way

Correct me If wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for your specific question, but I find the easiest way to get started developing with Umbraco 5 is to use the project templates for Visual Studio.

This way you'll have the complete solution structure created for you. I don't know if it works with the Express versions, though.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e932c31-de32-4adf-9e58-a16c4aca0716

Comment: I have already tried the template ,but it doesnt seem to work with web developer.